# Background Location Not Get in Lock Screen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I AM Working app that required to get Location in every minutes without using map, But when Mobile is Lock and app go to background the location not getting.

I facing errors

I/flutter (13751): PlatformException(SERVICE_STATUS_ERROR, Location service status couldn't be determined, null, null)
Getting location -> PlatformException(PERMISSION_DENIED, Background location permission denied, null, null)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EVvZ.jpg)

I try following Plugin
flutter_background 1.2.0
flutter_background_geolocation: ^4.10.2
background_fetch: ^1.1.5
background_location: ^0.8.1
flutter_background_service 2.4.6
But its not Working, Please Help me

Comment: Share code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Enable background execution
On iOS, you need to enable the "Background Modes" capability and select "Location updates" in Xcode. On Android, you need to add the android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

I try This but Phone Not access to background location